# How to set wrap_content with min height on view OnMeasure?

Tags: android, android-view

I set minimal height for view that extends button

```
@Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int h = resolveSize(minHeight, heightMeasureSpec);
    if (h < minHeight) h = minHeight;
    setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, h);
    rectBG.set(0, 0, MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), h);
    mBgPaint.setShader(
        new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, rectBG.bottom, colorStart, colorEnd, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
}
```

But when I set large text, my view does not extends. How to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you call `super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)` and then you're trying to perform your calculations.

You should either rely on calling `super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)` OR you should use `setMeasuredDimension`.

Unless there is some other issue with your `View`, deleting `super` call, should fix your issue.